# Is there a way to make have Safari run some javascript load after each loaded page?

Tags: safari, javascript

I want to configure Safari to run a piece of javascript after each page I visit. The same peace of js should be run after any web page I visit is loaded. How can I configure Safari for this?

Comment: @nicael Do you want to configure your Safari in a way to run a piece of javascript code after each page you visit or are you developing web pages and want to make sure that a js function only runs after the page is loaded?

Comment: @patrix I want to configure Safari to run a piece of javascript after each page I visit. The same peace of js should be run after any web page I visit is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Greasemonkey or "User scripts" were the ones that popularized this.

For one option on Mac/Safari, please see http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/20718/greasekit